# An ideal in a ring of polynomials and a field extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $K\subseteq L$ be fields and $I$ an ideal of $K[x_1,...,x_n]$. I want to show that $IL[x_1,...,x_n]\cap K[x_1,...,x_n] =I$.

The inclusion $I \subseteq IL[x_1,...,x_n]\cap K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is clear, so my actual problem is to show that, given $f\in I$ and $g \in L[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $fg \in K[x_1,...,x_n]$, then $fg \in I$.

I believe we should be able to prove that, under those circumstances, actually $g\in K[x_1,...,x_n]$ (then the result would follow since $I$ is an ideal).

I have a proof for the case $n=1$, but it works through the Euclidean algorithm (that is, it strongly uses the fact that $K[x],L[x]$ are Euclidean domains; however that is not the case when $n>1$).

Any ideas? Maybe some Galois theory?